# Any possible way to hide my web-part in Office 365

Tags: office-365

Is there any way I can show my webpart only to people who have full control on website ?

I have a webpart which creates a sub site, but I want it to show only to people who have full control, but I can't see a way as in office 365 I can't use DoesUserHavePermissions method.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: nope, not yet , it's a custom webpart, i can't find audience, also it's a web template, would setting will be saved when new site will be created, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider creating an [audience](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/manage-sharepoint-online-audiences-HA102772738.aspx) that contains your SharePoint group(s) with Full Control.

Then target your web part to the new audience:

1. Edit the page and then choose Edit web part
2. Expand the Advanced section
3. Add new audience to Target Audiences

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do that by wrapping whatever content you want to show in a SecurityTrimmedControl, and passing the appropriate permissions.

http://fusionovation.com/post/2008/09/18/security-trimmed-controls-in-sharepoint.aspx